# Prevent the pollution of the global scope

Tags: javascript, global-variables

We're trying to enforce JavaScript best practices for the project we're working on, one of the limitations we're trying to set is to not pollute the global scope.

We have an HTML template used for every page structured like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <!-- Page content here -->
        <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.js'></script>
        <!-- Page scripts here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to do is "lock" the `window` object and prevent any addition to it (e.g. `var foo = 'foo';` in global scope or `window['foo'] = 'foo';`) before the page scripts runs but after the libraries have loaded.

I already looked at [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), [`Object.seal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) but they don't work for the `window` object (they raise a `TypeError: can't change object's extensibility` exception).

I also looked at "cleanup" scripts like these:

```javascript
// Include this after the libraries.
(function(window) {
    var cache = {};
    for (var key in window) cache[key] = key;
    window.cache = cache;
})(window);

// Include this after all scripts.
(function(window) {
    var taint = {};
    for (var key in window) taint[key] = key;
    for (var key in window.cache) = delete taint[key];
    for (var key in taint) delete window[key];
})(window);
```

But they only clean-up the global scope, they don't prevent the pollution in the first space.

Is it possible to do it? We don't care if the solution breaks the JavaScript code polluting the global scope, we'll consider it a plus since it will force the developer to follow best practices.

P.s. Yes, I do know the best solution would be code reviews, sadly they're not feasible in our situation so we're looking for a catch-all solution.

Answer (score -1):

To lock global variables from the var keyword, wrap your code in an anonymous closure.

```
(function(){
  // ... Your code ...
}();
```

You can prevent assignment to window in chrome with the following.

```
Object.preventExtensions(window)
```

Comment: Your solution does not work: in Firefox 27 throws a `TypeError: can't change object's extensibility` exception and stops the execution of the script, in Chrome 33 and Internet Explorer 11 does not throw an exception but does not prevent the creation of new objects.

Comment: Where are you running it? If I open a console in Chrome this prevents me creating variables or adding to window.

This is Chrome 33.

Comment: I made a simple HTML page (you can find the code at https://gist.github.com/kappa7194/9481918) and hosted it in IISExpress. Creating a variable with `var foo = 'foo';` is not prevented, only `window.bar = 'bar';` is blocked and only in Chrome; Firefox raises an exception and Internet Explorer silently swallows the error.